# How to unserialise the PHP SESSION serialised value?

Tags: php, session

I stored a PHP SESSION values into DynamoDB, the following serialized structure is getting from on_session_write() function using session_set_save_handler(),

```
id|s:26:"rj4n98n6371vpgj8h5s10lmoh2";matt|N;SmartyValidate|a:1:{s:7:"default";a:4:{s:16:"registered_funcs";a:2:{s:8:"criteria";a:0:{}s:9:"transform";a:0:{}}s:10:"validators";a:0:{}s:8:"is_error";b:0;s:7:"is_init";b:1;}}language_id|i:1;language|s:3:"eng";
```

I tried PHP serialize() and unserialize() functions but it's not working. So, How can I un-serialize this value?

I need the output format as per the $_SESSION printed value.

Comment: what is the code you are using to do the serialize... this looks like a serialize call with some sort of string manipulation done on it.

Comment: For some reasons the serialized data is corrupted. The might being caused by a copy and paste error while posting here or a bug in your application. hard to say without knowing more

Comment: I am using  the `session_set_save_handler("on_session_start",   "on_session_end",
   "on_session_read",    "on_session_write",
   "on_session_destroy", "on_session_gc");` function and created a function on_session_write($key, $val) { echo $val;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says about [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

> While the data looks similar to `serialize()` please note it is a different format which is speficied in the `session.serialize_handler` ini setting.

The setting [`session.serialize_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) defaults to `php`, which means PHP is using the internal [`session_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php) and [`session_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php) functions.

> `session_decode()` decodes the serialized session data provided in `$data`, and populates the `$_SESSION` superglobal with the result.

Example:

```
<?php
session_start();
$str = 'id|s:26:"rj4n98n6371vpgj8h5s10lmoh2";matt|N;SmartyValidate|a:1:{s:7:"default";a:4:{s:16:"registered_funcs";a:2:{s:8:"criteria";a:0:{}s:9:"transform";a:0:{}}s:10:"validators";a:0:{}s:8:"is_error";b:0;s:7:"is_init";b:1;}}language_id|i:1;language|s:3:"eng";';
if (session_decode($str)) {
  print_r($_SESSION);
} else {
  die ("failed to decode session");
}
```

**Note:** You need to initialize a dummy session with `session_start()`. Otherwise `session_decode()` fails and does not populate the `$_SESSION` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = unserialize($value);
print_r($data);
```